# I need to change the On behalf of user in Salesforce

Tags: email, administration

I need to change the On behalf of user in automatic emails from an admin perspective.

"noreply@salesforce.com; on behalf of; Name "

I am aware of how to turn this off altogether but I just want to be able to change the user.

Currently these emails are sent to new community users.

I have looked around and don't see anything about switching the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"On Behalf [rest of the text]" is picked from the "From Name" value on Emails setting in the Community.

You can change it from your Community's *Administration --> Emails* as desired. Settings page screenshot below.

[image]